# How to resolve Inf. $y values when using MASS::boxcox?

Tags: r, mass

I am getting Inf. output for $y when running a box cox transformation using the MASS package. Here is a sample of the code I am running:

```r
sb2<- as.formula("yes~no+insured+sex2+racethx+mnhlth53+rthlth53+age13x")

 meps_analytic2 %>%
   filter(as.logical(yes))%>%
   MASS::boxcox(sb2,lambda=seq(-1,1,len=5),plotit=FALSE,data=.)
$x
[1] -1.0 -0.5  0.0  0.5  1.0

$y
[1] Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf

> summary(meps_analytic2)
     age13x      racethx   mnhlth53 rthlth53 sex2          no           yes       
 19     :  579   1: 7792   1:9329   1:6252   0:13967   FALSE: 1875   FALSE:24304  
 26     :  559   2:10196   2:7354   2:8163   1:12212   TRUE :24304   TRUE : 1875  
 22     :  539   3: 5435   3:7187   3:7759                                        
 21     :  534   4: 2094   4:1887   4:3125                                        
 25     :  533   5:  662   5: 422   5: 880                                        
 29     :  533                                                                    
 (Other):22902                                                                    
 insured  
 0: 7264  
 1:18915
```

I've tried running `is.finite()` and `is.nan()` for all variables that make up `sb2`, but no infinite values or NaNs are found. What would cause me to keep getting `Inf` responses for $y?? I have also tried changing class of variables to as.logical, as.numeric, etc.

Comment: Can we please have a reproducible example?? At the very least, what is `summary(meps_analytic2)`?  What is `sb2` ?

Comment: It will be better/clearer to edit your question to include the output of `summary(meps_analytic2)` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've filtered your data set so that there is no variation in your response variable (they are all `yes == TRUE`, which will get coerced to a numeric value of 1.0);

```r
dd <- data.frame(y=1, x = 1:10)
MASS::boxcox(y~x, data = dd, plotit = FALSE)
```

results:

```r
$x
 [1] -2.0 -1.9 -1.8 -1.7 -1.6 -1.5 -1.4 -1.3 -1.2 -1.1 -1.0 -0.9 -0.8 -0.7 -0.6
[16] -0.5 -0.4 -0.3 -0.2 -0.1  0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9
[31]  1.0  1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9  2.0

$y
 [1] Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf
[20] Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf
[39] Inf Inf Inf
```